# Can you include .Trash-999 from other media in Trash?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, files, usb-drive, sd-card

Can you include the "/.Trash-999" from external media in the Trash folder on Ubuntu? Like, the trash from all media and the system Trash shows up in Trash, similar to Windows Trash?